# EXPORT_SYMBOL in header causes "exported twice" errors

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, c99

I have a header file with the declaration of several global variables in the following format:

**constants.h**

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

extern unsigned var;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(var);

#endif
```

**constants.c**

```
#include "constants.h"
unsigned var = 10;
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "constants.h"
```

When I try to compile the kernel module, I get the following error for each respective exported symbol:

```
WARNING: /home/vilhelm/proj/constants: 'var' exported twice. Previous export was in /home/vilhelm/proj/foo.ko
```

I suspect that the symbols are being exported every time I include the **constants.h** header file, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't the include guard in **constants.h** prevent the `EXPORT_SYMBOL(var)` from being read multiple times?

Comment: I think that you should move EXPORT_SYMBOL macro to constants.c file. This way you will have it exported just once. Notice, that every time you include header it actually copy-pastes it into your c file. This way macro will fire every time you include constants.h as you noticed.

Comment: I realize that it is being fired multiple times because of the includes, but I'm more interested in understanding why the include guards don't prevent this from happening.

Comment: When you compile this code you create two object files. First is constants.o which comes from constants.h and constants.c, the second is foo.o created out of foo.c and constants.h. Now, both of them export symbol var. When it comes to linking, linker sees that var is exported by constants.o and foo.o and emits warning. Header guards cannot prevent this situation, because problem occurs during linking, not compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't the include guard in constants.h prevent the
>   EXPORT_SYMBOL(var) from being read multiple times?

The include guard prevents the header from being included more than once in the *same* source file. It can't prevent it from being included via *multiple* source files. Remember that the objects from all the sources get linked into a single object, and hence the conflict.

Let's say you have another header that is also included in the source files, called foo.h, which in turn includes constants.h. The file constants.c will try to include constants.h twice (once directly via constants.h and again via foo.h). The include guard works here, and constants.h will only be included once.

Same thing will happen with foo.c. It will try to include constants.h twice (once directly via constants.h and again via foo.h). The include guard works here too, and constants.h will only be included once.

But then the two objects, constants.o and foo.o will be linked together, each with its *single* copy of the EXPORT via constants.h. This adds up to two.

You want to make sure that exports appear in the final link just once. One way to do that would be to take them out of a common file like constants.h, and move them to a file called exports.c.